# Network request failed on Android when using fetch to post to cloud functions

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions, fetch-api

I am using the guide explained [here](https://medium.com/@wcandillon/uploading-images-to-firebase-with-expo-a913c9f8e98d)

to upload images to firebase cloud storage using cloud function as a middle ware or at least that what I understood from the guide.
My issue is with the fetch request at the client side:

```js
  const body = new FormData();
  body.append("picture", {
    uri: imageUri,
    name,
    type: type
  });
  await fetch(`${cloudFunctionUrl}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
     "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  }).then(async() => {
    // do things
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    reject(error);
  });
```

On iOS it works like a charm but on Android I get a network request failed error.

[image]

The publisher of the guide above declared that the method works for both iOS and Android.

Some topics suggested that the problem is with the headers of the request when it comes to Android, but didn't specify exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I had the same issue recently. The error is very vague and annoying. What helped me in debugging was using RequestBin to inspect the POST request https://requestb.in/

Try sending the request to RequestBin instead and see if it still fails. If it does, then it's something to do with the form data being incorrect. In my case, it was that I made a mistake on the image type. It was meant to be `image/jpeg`.

Comment: That is actually a pretty good idea ... will try it out let you know

Comment: @Kadi It was a type mistake as well. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was passing type = "jpg" while it should be type= "image/jpg". Thanks to Kadi

Comment: Nice! Glad you got it sorted!